Why do we typically think about circuits with nodes rather than meshes?
I was trying to wrap my head around the fact that voltages have a ground reference but currents are absolute, and yet, despite this fundamental difference, they are somehow mathematical duals of each other. This fact always made me uneasy and confused when converting between dual circuits and quantities.
After thinking about this a lot, I realized that currents can have references too. How? Just use mesh currents instead of branch currents. I vaguely knew that meshes are analogous to nodes, but never made the full connection between them until today. We don't notice the existence of a "mesh ground" in electrical analysis because the mesh ground (even in mesh-current analysis) usually ends up being in the space on the outside of the circuit, and so nobody ever notices its existence. But it is perfectly valid to define any mesh inside of a circuit as the current ground. Then all the mesh currents change appropriately, while the branch currents remain the same (just like changing the voltage ground changes all node voltages but leaves all voltage drops alone).
That observation made me want to seek a deep understanding of why we treat voltages and currents the way we usually do in the first place. It is conceivable that instead of using a node paradigm, we could get by (and even derive additional insight) using a mesh paradigm. But mesh analysis usually only ends up being an academic factoid treated briefly in elementary circuit analysis classes. Why is that? Why do we use a voltage node-current branch paradigm instead of a voltage drop-current mesh paradigm? They are pretty much equivalent. Treating both of them side by side could also help eliminate the plague of students being deathly afraid of doing any sort of magnetic field analysis, because the mental image of magnetic and electric fields in a circuit would be more complete.

Both meshes (aka KVL) and nodal (aka KCL) are simultaneously present in a graph theoretic approach (big-picture, linear algebra.) A matrix is also a transformation from one space to another space. There are also two nullspaces associated with these matrix transforms. The sum of the voltage differences working around a mesh loop is described by one such nullspace. The sum of the currents leaving and entering a node is described by the other nullspace. See a quick tour here and a better one here.

In graph theory, which has a great many applicable fields beyond electronics, vertices (nodes) are considered to be potentials (and this can be taken to be about anything, not just voltages) and edges (anything connecting two vertices) are considered to be fluxes (and again, this doesn't have to mean currents.) I would suggest you go through the videos I've picked out for you and listen well. Once you have done so, then you may still have some questions remaining. But they will be much sharper and more pointed ones, I think. Best wishes!

You write "voltages have a ground reference", but this is not necessarily true. A voltage is always a measurement between 2 nodes. You might choose a node in your circuit to label as ground and then use that ground node as one of the two measurement nodes for all of your subsequent voltage measurements, but that's almost entirely for your convenience. The choice of "ground node" is (at least technically) entirely arbitrary, but when you say "the voltage at node X is Y volts" what you're really saying is "the voltage between node X and node ground is Y volts".

A big one for me is voltage sources: nearly all electrical circuits are powered from a voltage source, not a current source. This provides a ground node and a (hopefully) fixed supply node that makes selecting an arbitrary "current node" superfluous. In addition, the way most circuits are designed, with multiple sections powered from the same supply and ground rails, lends itself to nodal analysis as they can be analyzed in isolation. Consider a simple circuit with two resistors in parallel with a voltage source. Nodal analysis can give you the current independently through each one; mesh analysis requires you to consider them together.

Voltage sources are actually easier to deal with in mesh analysis than node analysis. In mesh analysis you just add them to the mesh equation. In node analysis you have to introduce supernodes and adapt your whole equation structure to account for voltage sources.

To me it doesn't make sense to try to endow current with some fictitious property of "relativeness", as we do with potential, because current already has an absolute and meaningful zero. Even if you did, and you were right, it would be of little use. If you insist on having a relative  current, surely it wouldn't be with respect to current in another conductor, it should be motion of electrons with respect to the position of atomic nuclei in the same conductor. That way, if all the conductor atoms accelerated to the right, then all the mobile electrons would also accelerate by the same amount, in the same direction, and current-difference would be unchanged, in the same way raising the potential of one terminal of a cell  raises potential of the other end by the same amount, preserving the potential difference.
If your idea of a reference current were true, then you could raise all currents in all meshes by the same amount, without altering circuit state, but that's clearly not true. All potential differences would change too. This isn't the case for potentials, as you pointed out, for you can change all potentials at all nodes everywhere in a circuit by the same amount, without changing state or behaviour. I think you've already grokked what I'm about to say, but just in case:
Instead of applying "relativeness" to current, dispense with the concept of "absoluteness" of potential, which has no unambiguous state of zero-ness. The only meaningful or consequential "volt" is a potential difference.
There's no absolute potential anywhere in a circuit, but it might be useful to assign one, arbitrarily, for convenience. However KVL does not concern itself with individual potentials, which don't exist, it is all about potential differences. As currents are absolute, and can be zero, so are potential differences, which can also be zero. That's why KVL is all about potential differences, and not absolute potentials.
In nodal analysis, there's no need for a zero-volt potential anywhere, or any known/assumed absolute potential, because KVL and Ohm's law (and other I-V relationships like the diode equation) operate on potential differences, voltage across elements, which can be zero.
KVL says that all the potential differences in a loop add up to zero, and Ohm's law (or any relationship between voltage and current in some element) relates current through a thing to voltage across it. They don't care about the potential at either end of any element, they only care about the potential at one point relative to another, a potential difference, and that certainly can be zero.
KVL can be applied to any circuit with or without some fictitious, arbitrarily assigned zero-volt-absolute-potential (or any absolute potential for that matter) node somewhere. The boxed region below will have the same potential differences across each element within it, in all three scenarios, so KVL, KCL and Ohm's law can be applied to the box's contents, correctly revealing all currents and potential differences, without reference to anything outside it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Mesh analysis is an application of the superposition principle, forming always-true KVL statements that are a function of the superposition of all contributing currents. Each term in the resulting KVL expression is still a potential difference, a voltage across something, and those terms may be zero. They are no indication of absolute potential on either side of the element.
Changing any one current in any single mesh may seem like a "relative" change, but by that argument you could suggest that changing all currents by the same amount would not alter state, which is simply not the case. Similarly, changing any single potential difference, or all of them by the same amount, will also alter state.
By contrast, changing all absolute potentials by the same amount will preserve state, a property that you simply cannot attribute to current, relative or not.

Let me help you visualize what I mean. You have trouble accepting the fact that mesh currents are relative, but that's because you are conflating mesh currents with actual true absolute branch currents. These are not the same, just like node voltages and voltage drops are not the same. Consider a simple circuit with two meshes on a sphere. Place the two opposing nodes at the poles and make the three branches go directly north-south. Spread the meshes apart so that each covers 1/3 of the sphere. The two meshes now cover 2/3 of the sphere's surface, but the hole in the remaining 1/3 is...

indistinguishable from the two meshes. What was negative space is now a third mesh. That's because it was a mesh all along, we just didn't think of it as a mesh!. Now bring the two nodes at the poles closer to the equator recovering the original image of two meshes next to each other. Now distort the sphere into an infinite (projective) plane. The negative space that was clearly a mesh on the sphere is still a mesh on the plane (due to projective geometry). Where is that mesh? On the outside of the two meshes. We never noticed it's there, but it is there. It contributes 0 mesh current...

because we gave it zero current by default, by totally ignoring it in the first place. But if you now set the current in the "negative space mesh" to a non-zero number, you can confirm for yourself that if all the internal mesh currents are modified by the same delta, the branch currents obtained by adding the appropriate mesh currents together are unchanged! Just like voltage drops are unchanged by changes in a node reference. The outside mesh is therefore a conventional reference for mesh currents, and indeed currents are by this token relative. You can make a physical analogy by...

making mesh currents analogous to magnetic fields perpendicular to the loops. If you raise the baseline magnetic field everywhere in the 3d space by the same amount (up or down), it will not change the absolute currents because the contribution of the constant displacement of the magnetic field will cancel out in the analysis of branch currents. But it will technically change the reference mesh current

A mesh current can only be defined in a planar circuit. Not all circuits are planar, indeed some of the most important ones are not. This alone makes the concept of mesh currents less useful. I would say far less useful, verging on something that is taught in beginning circuit analysis only because it's always been done that way, to be quickly forgotten once the test is over.

That's only sort of true.  Loop analysis works fine on any graph.  Mesh analysis is basically just a shortcut to identify a linearly independent and complete set of loops when working with pen and paper.  The main reason for using nodal analysis rather than loop analysis is that it usually requires fewer equations.


Why do we typically think about circuits with nodes rather than meshes?

Node analysis is vastly more common than mesh analysis in the real world because we mostly use SPICE and related simulators for our analysis, and SPICE uses node analysis. This is mainly because it is easier (remember that SPICE originated in the 1970's when computers were much less capable) to set up the equations for node analysis --- you just make one equation for each node.
For hand analysis you shouldn't think of node analysis or mesh analysis as inherently superior. You should keep both tools in your toolbox and use the one that is more suitable for any given problem.

Perhaps SPICE works like SPICE because of the preference for nodal analysis, and not the other way around.

@ScottSeidman Isn't that the same as what I said? The people who wrote SPICE chose to use node analysis for a reason. But that reason doesn't usually apply to hand analysis.

It sounds to me like you assigned causality to SPICE -- i.e., we prefer node analysis because SPICE uses node analysis -- and I suspect it's the other way around, with SPICE using node analysis because that's what the people who coded SPICE liked to use.

@ScottSeidman I meant that nodal analysis is widely used because we use nodal analysis whenever we use SPICE. And we do our analysis by SPICE (and its descendants) more often than by other means. If SPICE is used (say) 80% of the time we do circuit analysis, and SPICE uses nodal analysis, then nodal analysis is being used for at least 80% of the analysis being done. It has nothing to do with people trying to do hand analysis the same way SPICE does its analysis. (Although understanding how SPICE works is an important reason to learn node analysis)

Because it is easy to choose a ground node and find voltages at other nodes. Since most circuits have voltage sources, it is easy to find voltages at various nodes using nodal analysis. After finding nodal voltages, KVL is used to find current in resistors assuming it is a simple DC circuit.
If there are capacitors or inductors in the circuit, nodal analysis is still applicable in AC circuits.Voltages in most transistor based circuits are calculated with nodal analysis for the same reason.

I am a bit unsure about your statement:

Then all the mesh currents change appropriately, while the branch currents remain the same (just like changing the voltage ground changes all node voltages but leaves all voltage drops alone).

Consider the circuit below, and the three meshes I have picked:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This circuit does not contain any generator, and therefore a valid (and unique, thanks to linearity) solution is for all currents to be zero, and voltages to be the same.
Let's call the meshes M6 M4 and M5, from the resistors that identify the currents.
$$
I_{R3} = I_6 + I_4\\
I_{R2} = I_6 - I_5\\
I_{R1} = I_4 + I_5
$$
While you can change all the three mesh currents by some amount \$\Delta I\$ like so:
$$
I_{R3} = I_6 + \Delta I + I_4 - \Delta I\\
I_{R2} = I_6 + \Delta I - I_5 - \Delta I\\
I_{R1} = I_4 - \Delta I + I_5 + \Delta I
$$
and still conserve the absolute current flowing in the three central resistors, you now have a "ring" current going through the external three resistors, which is impossible.
Keep in mind that the duality of current vs voltage you have in mind comes from the mathematical tools that we use to solve linear circuits, but they are very different physical phenomena and while one has an absolute reference, the other does not.

I don't see why you'd necessarily get a ring current. Writing I∞ for the final mesh current around the outside of the circuit, we get equations like IR5 = I5 + I∞; then changing I4, I5, I6 in the way you did and I∞ by -ΔI, we get equations like IR5 = I5 + ΔI + I∞ - ΔI that still conserve the absolute currents.

Although I accepted an answer, I'm still coming back to point out what I meant. No one seems to get this, which is understandable because it's not a common approach. But consider this analogy: voltage drop is like an absolute current because no matter what reference you choose as voltage ground, the drop is always the same; voltage node is like a mesh current; both of them are not absolute, and I think you have trouble visualizing how mesh currents can be not absolute. Consider a simple circuit with two meshes, and now place it on a sphere such that the top and bottom nodes are...

...directly at the poles, and the branches go from pole to pole. If each of the meshes covers 1/3 of the sphere's area, there is a total of 2/3 covered by meshes, and there is 1/3 of the sphere's surface left as a hole. But the hole looks exactly like the other meshes by the way we constructed this picture. So there are really three meshes. Now drag the two nodes you originally put at the poles closer to the equator. You now have two obvious meshes, but since we only moved the nodes elsewhere, the third mesh still exists in the negative space. Now distort the sphere into a plane. There you go

The ground mesh is actually on the outside of the circuit (by default), and we never noticed its existence because intuitively we set it to 0 without even thinking about it. But you can set the reference to be any other mesh, and all absolute currents will still remain the same, but now you will have a new mesh current running around the outside of the entire circuit.

Thanks for getting back on this topic @KKZiomek; I believe I understand what you mean now. This is certainly an interesting topic.
